# Converting a count down timer to a usable format

Tags: r, time, rstudio

I am trying to convert a count down timer from a character into a usable format, ideally a time format but numeric may work.

I have tried converting it using, as.POSIXct and also using the Chron package

Here is a dput of the DF

```
structure(list(Time = c("(-01:30)", "(-01:15)", "(-01:00)", "(-00:45)", 
"(-00:30)", "(-00:15)", "0", "+00:13", "+00:15", "+00:30", "+00:45"
)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I have already removed the brackets from the time column using

```
sd$Time = (gsub("[(),//]", "", sd$Time))
```

Then tried ton convert using the following

```
sd$Time <-  as.POSIXct(sd$Time, format="%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be `strptime`

```
strptime(sub("^0$", "00:00", gsub("[-+()]", "", sd$Time)), format = "%M:%S")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this unfortunately removes all the values after the zero, so once the timer starts to count up.  It also converts the minutes into hours and the seconds into minutes.  I would like to be able to draw graphs with Time on the x axis, could this be done if we converted it to numeric? Thanks again.

Comment: @TDaw IN your example, i didn't find any other value after the `)`

Comment: I have changed the question to only include the dput of the sd$Time column

Comment: @TDaw  Is that format `MM::SS` or `HH::MM`  Because it is workig for me `strptime(sub("^0$", "00:00", gsub("[-+()]", "", sd$Time)), format = "%H:%M")
 [1] "2019-05-08 01:30:00 EDT" "2019-05-08 01:15:00 EDT" "2019-05-08 01:00:00 EDT" "2019-05-08 00:45:00 EDT"
 [5] "2019-05-08 00:30:00 EDT" "2019-05-08 00:15:00 EDT" "2019-05-08 00:00:00 EDT" "2019-05-08 00:13:00 EDT"
 [9] "2019-05-08 00:15:00 EDT" "2019-05-08 00:30:00 EDT" "2019-05-08 00:45:00 EDT"`

Comment: @TDaw in that case `strptime(sub("^0$", "00:00", gsub("[-+()]", "", sd$Time)), format = "%M:%S")`